# Flume Kafka sink not able to write complete messages to Kafka Broker

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, hortonworks-data-platform, flume-ng, sink

I have written a process where I'm generating messages thru custom flume source and **Flume Kafka sink** provided by **Hortonworks** to write into **Kafka brokers**. 
During this process i have noticed that if KAFKA broker is already running and then i start my Flume agent it delivers each and every message to the Kafka broker properly but when i starts Kafka broker when Flume agent is already running, KAFKA broker is not able to receive all the messages. 
When i run **Kafka Console consumer** to check the counts of messages received i noticed it is dropping few records from beginning and few records from the end.

I have tried multiple mix and match in **Flume.conf** but still it is working as expected.

> Below are the configuration parameter which i have provided to
>   **Flume.conf -**

```
agent.channels = firehose-channel
agent.sources = stress-source
agent.sinks = kafkasink 
#################################
# Benchmark Souce Configuration #
#################################
agent.sources.stress-source.type=com.kohls.flume.source.stress.BenchMarkTestScenriao
agent.sources.stress-source.size=5000
agent.sources.stress-source.maxTotalEvents=30000
agent.sources.stress-source.batchSize=200
agent.sources.stress-source.throughputThreshold=4000
agent.sources.stress-source.throughputControlSeconds=1
agent.sources.stress-source.channels=firehose-channel  
#################################
# Firehose Channel Configuration #
#################################
agent.channels.firehose-channel.type = file
agent.channels.firehose-channel.checkpointDir = /data/flume/checkpoint
agent.channels.firehose-channel.dataDirs = /data/flume/data
agent.channels.firehose-channel.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.firehose-channel.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent.channels.firehose-channel.useDualCheckpoints=1
agent.channels.firehose-channel.backupCheckpointDir=/data/flume/backup

############################################
# Firehose Sink Configuration - Kafka Sink #
############################################
agent.sinks.kafkasink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
agent.sinks.kafkasink.topic = backoff_test_17
agent.sinks.kafkasink.channel=firehose-channel
agent.sinks.kafkasink.brokerList = sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667
agent.sinks.kafkasink.batchsize = 200
agent.sinks.kafkasink.requiredAcks = 1
agent.sinks.kafkasink.kafka.producer.type = async
agent.sinks.kafkasink.kafka.batch.num.messages = 200
```

I have also tried to analyses the flume log and noticed that the flume metrics are properly showing the **PUT** and **TAKE** count.

Please let me know if anyone has any pointer to solve this issue.
 **Appreciating your help in advance.**

Comment: Can i get some help from Flume users???

Comment: have you considered using the sync producer type as part of your troubleshooting?